# Firebase java desktop application does not work on Windows

Tags: java, windows, firebase

I'm currently trying to incorporate **firebase** to my java desktop application. Initially, I develop my app using **Netbeans** under linux environment and it turns out to be fine. I can persist data to firebase.

But when I clone my project and continue working under **windows**, it does **not** work. I didn't change anything.

I tried switching my windows firewall off but it's still the same. Any idea on what's causing this? Or is there any configuration to add? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried writing a bare bones version on Linux and trying it on windows? Also do you get any errors? Are your firebase library files in the correct location for windows? Do the library files need to be different on windows?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Please be more specific and provide errors, code, etc.

Comment: The problem is, it doesn't have any errors @ifconfig. I tried to surround it with **try-catch** block and it's not throwing any errors,

Comment: @sorifiend On the documentation that I followed, https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup, it didn't mention any platform specific configuration. Or there might be but I missed it.

In **Netbeans**, all my libraries are stored in **lib** directory inside the project. I tested it and the libraries can be found.

Comment: @Arjun OK, that's good to know, so the next step is to write a very small piece of code (in a new project) just to see if firebase works in your windows development environment. Maybe just see if you can establish a connection. Let us know your results.